# R package to do a regularized "quasi-binomial" regression

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, lasso, regularization

I have data that I want to model with the following data generating process:

$y_{i}$~$binomial(p_{i}, N_{i})$

$logit(p_{i}) =\alpha + \beta*X_{i}$

This sort of thing is easily handled in R's glm function, but I want to be able to run Lasso or Ridge. It's possible to approximate this sort of thing by doing a continuous linear regression in GLMNET and weighting by $N_{i}$, but I have a mix of $N_{i}$ in both the single digits and the triple digits, so the normal approximation fails fairly badly.

Are there any packages out there that can do regularized regression with this link function?

Comment: Euhm in `glmnet` you can just use argument `family="binomial"`, right?

Comment: The quasibinomial family in glm do not affect the estimation, it only affects the standard errors calculated after estimation.  Likewise, just use binomial family in glmnet.

Comment: Ha sorry I had missed the quasi... part in the title of your question, as that doesn't reappear in the actual question - other possibility could be to take into account overdispersion using a random intercept, and use R package glmmLasso for regularization